# node-expat causing npm to fail with node install soap

Tags: macos, node.js, soap, osx-lion, npm

I am trying to install node js soap module via NPM on Mac OSX, tried hard enough to manually install and point to expat.h etc didn't work

**npm install soap**

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/soap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/soap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-expat
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-expat
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request

> node-expat@1.6.0 install /Users/test/test1/node_modules/soap/node_modules/node-expat
> node-waf configure build

Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local 
Checking for header expat.h              : not installed 
/Users/test/test1/node_modules/soap/node_modules/node-expat/wscript:14: error: the configuration failed (see '/Users/test/test1/node_modules/soap/node_modules/node-expat/build/config.log')
npm ERR! node-expat@1.6.0 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@1.6.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "soap"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/test/test1
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.33
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message node-expat@1.6.0 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! message `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/test/test1/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Have googled it installed expat manually etc but no luck. Please note Xcode 4.3 is installed and also command line support is in place.

I am really not sure how I can  get rid of the following two messages. Please help.

```
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for header expat.h              : not installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine now fixed in 1.6.1 :)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: Oh ok Thanks, I am the Author a such, but added it as an answer just because it works now with out issues. This question will be almost usage until some on is trying expat 1.6.0

Comment: ohoh sorry, didn't notice that you were the author. So don't forget to mark your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

node-waf has been removed in node 0.8, and binary module authors are being encouraged to migrate to node-gyp instead

Comment: so whats the way forward? I have to wait till soap module is fixed? any workarounds?

Comment: Degrade your node to 0.6 or bug the author to fix his module

Answer (score 0):

You need the libexpat development headers, try install the libexpat1-dev package with homebrew or ports or whatever package manager...